# Exception while connecting to mysql in 000webhost

Tags: java, mysql

I have created a database on 000webhost.com and now I am trying to connect to the database through java as:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql14.000webhost.com/a2509514_Email", username, pass);
```

But when I execute it I am getting the following exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection timed out: connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:372)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:215)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at trapack.Experiment.sample(Experiment.java:20)
at trapack.Experiment.main(Experiment.java:35)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at trapack.Experiment.sample(Experiment.java:20)
at trapack.Experiment.main(Experiment.java:35)
```

There is no direct discussion about this specific topic so any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to use SSL (or a VPN).

Comment: sorry but what's that?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem when I was using MySQL in AWS (Amazon Web Services - Cloud Computing)

I had to give permission to my computer IP in the site (AWS).

I recommend you to use http://www.heidisql.com/ to test if you can connect to your database in 000webhost. If you succed, the error is in your Java code, if you fail to connect it can be your credentials, security configuration of your host site or just a horrible connection link you have there.

Give us more information about your problem so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the connection string provided by 000webhost when you create the user.

000webhost.com creates their own string or host name for creating connection..

Hope it will works.
Thanks

Comment: yeah connection string is the same that they have provided

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you must upgrade your account.

The free MySQL from 000webhost doesn't allow you to connect from external applications, just from within pages hosted in their domain.

Please check: [How can I connect to MySQL from my computer?](http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=27)

Comment: i guess to upgrade i have to pay

Comment: Do you know any other free hosting site?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think I've connected to a remote database in Heroku. Also, if you sign up for Amazon Web Services, they let you use it free for a year (with certain limits).